# Anomaly detection in Multivariate timeseries

Tags: regression, time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, anomaly-detection

I am working on an algorithm which will detect the anomalies in multivariate timeseries. 
Suppose there is a time series[image]

My algorithm will compute two equations: **lower_equation_y** and **upper_equation_y**. 
**lower_equation_y = slope1 x X1 + slope2 x X2 + slope3 x X3 + lower_bound_intercept** 
**upper_equation_y = slope1 x X1 + slope2 x X2 + slope3 x X3 + upper_bound_intercept**

*The future datapoints of Y which will not be in the range of lower and upper equation will be marked as anomaly. I'm only interested in finding anomalies in Y at a time.*

**STEPS I followed :**

1. Compute multiple regression equation taking y as target and all x's as independent.
2. Compute lower bound and upper bound intercept and prepare the equation
3. Then mark anomaly based on the equations

**Problem with above approach :**

1. It is not capturing the relationships between the x's, because regression don't capture the relationships between independent.

**Updated Approach**

1. I thought to use VAR instead of regression, it will capture the dependencies among the x's.
2. The problem with VAR is I have to give stationary independent variables to the model

**My questions**

1. There is trend component in my independent variables, if I make it stationary it will affect the values of slope, will that affect my anomaly calculation? Because to prepare an equation I need the trend part as well.

I stuck at this problem, can someone please help me with my approach any new idea or improvement in the existing for computing anomalies will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you could include trend as a separate deterministic variable to obtain VARX where X stands for exogenous variables. Then having variables with trends would not be a problem for the VAR (now VARX) model.